# Sending a message from an event to a transition?

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to send a message to activate the transition in the second pic attached. I've used this command line

```
deliver("nuovo epicentro")
```

but it doesn't work. The transition is not in the main section, but in the agent Tir, while the event is in the main environment. How can i fix it?

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xszmO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXAsp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which 'tir' agent you want to send it to, how would AnyLogic know?

So you could write 'tirs.get(0).deliver...'. This will send it to the first agent in the population of 'tirs'. Note that it will throw an error if there is no agent in that population

On a broader note: you need to start understanding model hierarchy and how to navigate it. Do all the tutorials in the help, they show this quite a bit.

Comment: And if I send the message to all of these agents?

Comment: For-loop across all in the population. Or `sendToAll(tirs)`

Comment: Description: The method get(int) in the type AgentArrayList<Tir> is not applicable for the arguments (Tir).
This is the error if I type in the action event
"for (Tir t : tirs){

 tirs.get(t).deliver("nuovo epicentro");
}"

Comment: please always open new questions for new problems, SOF does not work like a forum, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow